Moengage integration in Flutter not working on Android, events not visible on dashboard
I'm currently integrating Moengage into my Flutter application, but I'm encountering an issue specifically on Android. I've followed the setup instructions provided in the documentation, and while the application is running without errors, the events fired from the application are not appearing on the Moengage dashboard.
Interestingly, I've also implemented Moengage in a similar manner for iOS, and it seems to be working fine on that platform. However, on Android, I'm facing this problem consistently.
Here's a summary of what I've done:
Followed the integration steps outlined in the Moengage documentation for Flutter.
Ensured that the SDK is initialized correctly in the Flutter app.
Verified that events are being triggered from the application code.
Despite these efforts, I'm unable to see any events reflected on the Moengage dashboard for Android.
Could someone please provide insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue? Has anyone encountered a similar problem while integrating Moengage with a Flutter app on Android? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Setup Code :
MainActivity.kt
import com.moengage.flutter.MoEInitializer
import com.moengage.core.MoEngage
import com.moengage.core.DataCenter
import android.os.Bundle
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication


class MainActivity: FlutterApplication() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val moEngage: MoEngage.Builder = MoEngage.Builder(this, "TOKEN HERE",DataCenter.DATA_CENTER_1)
        MoEInitializer.initialiseDefaultInstance(applicationContext, builder = moEngage)
    }
}

build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', "*.aar"])
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.3"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx")
    implementation ("com.moengage:moe-android-sdk:13.00.00")
    implementation("androidx.core:core:1.6.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.4.0")
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0")
}


Hi MoEngage supports Test and Live environments, can you please confirm, if you are checking the right environment. Android automatically sends the events to test environment for debug builds and live environment for release builds.

I am triggering events in debug mode and checking them in test environment only.

We are facing a similar issue, albeit with react-native. Events are coming through fine on iOS and Android devices and Android Studio emulator. However, events are not coming through for Genymotion emulator. We don't want to brush this to the side and only use AS as this could have implications for certain Android devices.

Although you don't see in recent events, if you create a user, can you at least see that in segments? I am seeing user but not event which may be similar to your situation.

Update:
The events are not visible in recent events section but they are visible in  user's profile.
